# How can I parallelize my macOS app tasks as much as possible without running out of memory?

Tags: swift, macos, memory, parallel-processing, grand-central-dispatch

I have a Swift app running on macOS. It batch-processes images. I don't know ahead of time how big these images are going to be, and what hardware my app is going to run on - these are both user dependent.

I use GCD to parallelize the processing of the images as it can really accelerate the throughput.

However, in some cases, too much parallelization can hurt: if the user processes high resolution images, the parallelization creates too much memory pressure, and the system's performance becomes really poor.

So I'd like to find a way to "feed my parallel task processor" at a rate that maximizes parallelization while keeping the workload in RAM (so there aren't any triggers to paging & swapping: I want to avoid disk IO).

Any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: How do you parallelize? I mean do you split each image across the available cores or do you process multiple images in parallel?

Comment: I process multiple images in parallel. If I could parallelize the work for ONE image, this problem wouldn't be as important. Perhaps I need to put more effort into that avenue (it also has the benefit of lower latency when we only process one image), but the question still stands.

Comment: Update: what I was afraid of ends up being true - the part that can be parallelized doesn't benefit that much from parallelization. The overhead of creating parallel tasks takes away the advantages of the CPU efficiency gains. The best parallelization factor for this part is 2 (beyond that no more gains are achieved), which is nice, but it only starts making a difference with massive images (8192x8192), which isn't the nominal use case. For the nominal use case, I think the minor improvement doesn't warrant the code complexity incurred. So the question really still stands.

Comment: Can you share your code? What is the image processing you are actually doing? What sort of throughput are you getting with what size/type of images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a TokenBucket-type of singleton that deals with admission control based on memory requirements. It gets initialized such that 80% of the RAM can be used by my app.

```
let memoryGate = MemoryGate(maxBytes: ProcessInfo.processInfo.physicalMemory*8/10)
```

When someone wants to perform a memory intensive operation, it has to request() memory from it. If there isn't enough memory, the call blocks until there is. After being done, the thread has to release() the memory.

Code:

```
class MemoryGate {

    private let maxBytes : UInt64
    private var availableBytes : Int64

    private let cv = NSCondition()

    init(maxBytes: UInt64) {
        self.maxBytes = maxBytes
        self.availableBytes = Int64(maxBytes)
        Log.debug?.message("maxBytes=\(maxBytes)")
    }

    public func request(amount: UInt64) {
        Log.debug?.message("Resquesting \(amount) bytes")
        cv.lock()

        // If the amount is bigger than the max allowed, no amount of waiting is going
        // to help, so we go through and let the other smaller jobs be held back until
        // memory is freed
        if (amount <= maxBytes) {
            while (availableBytes < Int64(amount)) {
                cv.wait()
            }
        }

        availableBytes -= Int64(amount)

        Log.debug?.message("Got \(amount) bytes. availableBytes=\(availableBytes)")
        cv.unlock()
    }

    public func release(amount: UInt64) {
        cv.lock()
        availableBytes += Int64(amount)
        Log.debug?.message("Released \(amount) bytes. availableBytes=\(availableBytes)")
        cv.broadcast()
        cv.unlock()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a [GCD dispatch source](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1385630-dispatch_source_create) for memory pressure events. Not sure how your code is structured, but would it be possible to create parallel tasks until you get a `DISPATCH_MEMORYPRESSURE_WARN` event, then stop making tasks or even kill some?

Comment: That's a bit tricky because in batch processing, I get a list of photos that the user wants to process (let's say 500), and from that I need to throw them into a DispatchQueue managed by GCD. Supposedly GCD knows best how it's going to use the available CPU resources, so I'm supposed to just throw them all in for GCD to do its job. But once they're in, they run their life: I don't think I can take them back. That's when they all start allocating memory. By the time I get DISPATCH_MEMORYPRESSURE_WARN it's too late - the tasks are already sent to GCD for processing.